# Passing parameter to report in Report Viewer, problem

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer, report

Well I have table at my Report.rdl and I want To generate it dinamicly like GridView

```
        Reports.dsReport ds = new dsReport();
        Reports.dsReportTableAdapters.sp_PaymentsTableAdapter daInformation =
            new dsReportTableAdapters.sp_PaymentsTableAdapter();
        try
        {               
            daInformation .Fill(ds.sp_Procedure
                                               , ID
                                               , Name
                                               , Number
                                               , startDate
                                               , endDate
                                               , payerID);
        }
        catch { }          

        DataTable dtPaymentInfo = ds.Tables["sp_Payments"];

        List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();

        parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("PeriodStart", startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
        parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("PeriodEnd", endDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));

        foreach(DataTable item in dtPaymentInfo.Rows)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < item.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               int status =  (int)item.Rows[i][2];

               string paymentName;
               if(status == 0)
                  paymentName=status.ToString() + " EURO";                   
               if(status == 1)
                  paymentName=status.ToString() + " DOLLAR";  
               if(status == 2)
                  paymentName=status.ToString() + " Pound";    

            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("PaymentName", paymentName);
            }

        }


        rpvPaymentInformation.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);

        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
        rds.Name = "DataSet1";
        rds.Value = dtPaymentInfo;

        rpvPaymentInformation.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        rpvPaymentInformation.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        rpvPaymentInformation.LocalReport.Refresh();

        rpvPaymentInformation.ShowReportBody = true;
```

This is Page's CodeBehind

And when my Table control generates some datas it populates with [status + "  EURO"]

But in database status has 1, 2 values too.

How can I solve this problem? :(

Comment: Can you rephrase the last part of your question? Not very clear as to what the problem is.

Comment: Is the problem the way the table control is displaying the status field?  Or is it that the parameter you are sending it that includes "DOLLAR" and "Pound" values causing problems?

Comment: @ Bala R

well in database's table there are status field with type Int
and here in asp page which uses reportviewer want to filter this status like that 
if status = 0 then mast be status + " Euro "
case status =1  status + " Dollar"
and last if status = 3 status + " pound"
and I want to do it with Report Parameter if it's possible.

problem is that in report only displays status + " Euro"
But in table there are also statuses with 1 and 2 values
and must display status + " Dollar" and status + " Pound" too, but it did not do, despite I retrieve such values (1 or 2) from datatable

Comment: @Judah Sali 
From table I retrieve datas and it's working. But when I add this to Report Parameter "parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("PaymentName", paymentName)" after that when Page renders in report only shows "0 Euro", because in database status column the first record is 0. But as I told there are values 1 and 2 too.

Comment: You should consider rewriting your original question as there is still no clear problem being identified.

Answer (score 0):

It's still very unclear what you are trying to do, but I noticed that you are adding the parameter `PaymentName` to the report parameters multiple times.  I'm pretty sure you are just ending up with either the first or last parameter you added to the report and not all three.

It is possible that what you are trying to do is add multiple values to the parameter.  If that is what you want, then you are better off including your parameter in a table as part of the datasource of the report.  See here for how to use a table as a multiple value parameter: http://www.duttonsoftware.com/2008/09/25/easy-multi-value-parameters-in-sql-server-reporting-services/